# Has anyone gotten lldb expression evaluation to work with C++11 on Mavericks?

Tags: debugging, c++11, osx-mavericks, lldb

I've been trying for weeks now to get lldb working with C++11 on Mavericks, and I just cannot get it working reliably. Has anyone managed this? What exact steps did you take?

Symptoms I find include:

(1) Unable to invoke basic std functions, like if I have a vector v in the code, I cannot call "v.size()" (earlier StackOverflow responses agreed with this).

(2) Generally gets confused all the time about data types and classes. Sometimes it understands simple things, sometimes it just gives odd error messages, and misinterprets user types.

(3) If I stop the code and call a bunch of other functions, lldb sometimes just gets very confused, and I have seen utterly bizarre run-time behavior (e.g., I call a function from lldb and get logically impossible results, as if the call stack or memory was somehow mangled).

(4) Sometimes lldb just gives up and seems to lose track of where it is on the stack.

I know these are vague, but has anyone used lldb extensively for expression evaluation (not just breakpoints, but calling functions and methods from with debugger) and had lldb work? I have these very complex, very large datastructures and need an interactive debugger to manipulate them, and invoke methods on them, interactively (i.e., a repl).

Not part of the question, but if anyone knows of a true C++11 debugger that can call methods and evaluate functions at run time interactively, and works reliably on MacOS Mavericks, I'd be very grateful.

N.B. earlier MacOS versions are entirely different from Mavericks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about 2-4, they are not specific enough to really tell.  But #1 turns out to be a problem with the new C++ standard library on OS X.  It is pretty aggressive about inlining most of the std::* functions, and not creating out of line copies.  That's actually usually exactly what you want, but it is inconvenient for debugging!

You usually see errors like:

```
(lldb) expr my_vec.size()
error: call to a function 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >::size() const' ('_ZNKSt3__16vectorIiNS_9allocatorIiEEE4sizeEv') that is not present in the target
```

And that's because there is no function to call, there's only inlined versions sprinkled through-out your code.

In C++11 you can work around this if you know in advance you will want to call functions in some particular template class by putting:

```
template class std::vector<int>;
```

for instance, in you code somewhere. Probably want to do this inside some kind of #ifdef DEBUG construct, you wouldn't want to ship code this way.

Comment: There are many, many ways a debugger could be configured to be able to call STL functions if it wanted to. For one thing, lldb has access to the source code, it should be able to figure out basic data types from that. Be that as it may, have you been using lldb with C++ for a while on Mavericks and not had the problems 2-4 I mentioned? I'm profoundly disappointed at how ridiculously bad the debugging environment is for C++ on Mac - how can you have a debugger that can't call many basic functions? It's stymied my work, I have to make wrappers for every function in my program.

Comment: lldb does use "access to the source code" to implement its "data formatters".  For instance, if I have a vector of ints, I can just print the vector and the data formatter will print the size, and print the contents as if it were an array.  The thing we can't currently do is compile up a version of the template that corresponds to all the build settings you used in your app so it will be consistent with the class you use.  That requires some help from the compiler that is not present yet.  But in many cases the data formatters make this unnecessary.

Comment: And of course, if you can make available some examples showing your issues, please file them with bugreporter.apple.com.  That or pitching in to help make lldb better yourself (it is an open source project) are the two ways to actually make things better.

Comment: Well, I did not intend to criticize lldb as such. It makes no difference to me whether a problem is due to the compiler, the library, or the debugger. Since the same company owns or manages all three, it shouldn't matter. If I write "g++ -g foo.cpp" and then cannot step through my code, it's not really my responsibility as a user to care if the fault lies in the compiler's implementation of -g; in the STL implementation; or the lldb source.